# The number entered isn't the same as the result

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a problem with my code, the result of `debit.txt` is not the same as the input:

```
long int s;

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("saldo.txt");
cout << "Masukan jumlah saldo kredit : "; cin >> s;
outfile << s << endl;
outfile.close();
```

my `saldo.txt`

```
long int db;

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("debit.txt");
cout << "Masukan jumlah saldo kredit : "; cin >> db;
outfile << db << endl;
outfile.close();
```

my `debit.txt`

```
long int s, db;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("saldo.txt");
    infile >> s;
    cout << s << endl;

    infile.open("debit.txt");
    infile >> db;
    cout << db << endl;
    infile.close(); 

}
```

and this the result `cek.txt`

When I try to input 150 in `debit.txt` the result is a random number, but not for `saldo.txt`, can someone help me fix this ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not close "infile" object, before opening "debit.txt".
Please close the infile as said below

```
long int s, db;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("saldo.txt");
infile >> s;
cout << s << endl;


infile.close(); //close here.


infile.open("debit.txt");
infile >> db;
cout << db << endl;
infile.close();
```